# multiple roles in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

I want to design a role based system like Basecamp. A user can be editor of a brand and also he can be a worker in another brand. I'm using devise + cancan. How can i design a database for this situation? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a role model. In this scenario a user would `have_and_belong_to_many :roles` while a role would `have_and_belong_to_many :users`. This creates a many to many relationship between roles and users. See [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) RailsGuide for more info on associations.

In your CanCan ability.rb file you can do something like this (I am just guessing at your setup):

```
 can :manage, Brand do |brand|
  user.has_role?("brand_manager") && user.brands.include?(brand)
end
```

In your user.rb file it's helpful to write something like this:

```
def has_role?(name)
  role = Role.find_by_name(name)
  (self.roles.include?(role)) ? (return true) : (return false)
end
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[acl_system2](https://github.com/elmer/acl_system2). Its an old plugin, but checkout its readme file to see if it serves the purpose.